# app is still in development mode...Facebook - no option to login with Email for test user

Tags: swift, facebook, facebook-login

I am trying to test Facebook login on an iPhone X device but I am getting the following error as follows:

"This app is still in development mode..."

[image]

**When testing on a different iPhone X device I am given the option to log in with an Email address**, which I can then enter the details of the test user created in the Facebook Developers console.

I am not ready to submit to Facebook for review and approval so that is not an option and hence why I assume FB gives you the ability to create test users in the first place.

I am struggling to figure what the difference between the two devices is. I even logged out the real Facebook user from the Facebook app in an attempt to show me the option to log in with email but to no avail.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow these steps to make it live.

Login to facebook developer account https://developers.facebook.com/ -> goto you app dashboard -> then switch on to change status live (first you must need to fill privacy policy URL and etc. in basic setting)

See the following screenshot.

[image]

Comment: does this require your app to go through the Facebook review process to make it go Live?, because my app is not ready for review yet. I just want to test.

Comment: Furthermore, I don't have a privacy policy URL as yet, our website is still under development as well.

Comment: Yes, You must make status live and also you need to create a simple webpage which content privacy policy and required information.